# How to store daily hits for items using MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL database, I'm trying way of creating a table to track daily views on 100 items. Each day would insert a new row for each item. So the table columns would look like this:

```
| ItemID | ItemName | Hits |
```

Is there a  way to store daily hits for items?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: simply update hits columns on the basis of item id when the item is view.

Comment: This may be of use to you, as someone is doing the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659868/most-efficient-way-of-storing-daily-page-views-as-well-as-a-total-count

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is have a table with a structure like:

```
| item_hits     |
|---------------|
| itemID | date |
```

Then your SQL query could look like

```
SELECT count(*) FROM item_hits WHERE date = '2015/04/15' and itemID = 7;
```

You wouldn't need to save the itemName in the table, because you should be able to get the itemName by joining it to your items table.